# Looking for glTF to 3D Tiles open-source converter

Tags: gis, gltf, cesiumjs, 3d-model

I'm new to 3D geometry and WebRendering of 3d objects.

So, I came across a glTF to 3d Tile converter which seems to be taking up a lot of space post conversion. I don't exactly understand the reason for the inefficiency and this library accepts only Embedded glTFs.

The library's link : https://github.com/xuzhusheng/gltf-to-3d-tiles

It would be appreciated, if someone can help me optimize the library and provide any insights on how to make it efficient. Or, any other library which is efficient and useful for my use case, as I will be rendering it on CesiumJS.

Thank you!